# Why are there so many partitions in my system?

Tags: partitioning

[image]

As you can see above, there are so many partitions, some of them can be as small as 10MB, and these are only part of all partitions, there are more than 30 partitions in my system.

Can I delete them to re-collect the wasted disk spaces and how?

Comment: The `/dev/loop` devices are snap partitions - see Q&A above.

Comment: The only partitions I see on nvme1n1p(partition-number) are Microsoft Windows partitions. Mounted *loop* devices are not partitions; using no space on disk  (they are *logical* mounts on your system, that are created on boot & are used during operation of the system)

Comment: If you have Ubuntu (or a flavour of Ubuntu), I think your loop devices are used by snaps. Please run `lsblk -f /dev/loop*` in a wide terminal window to check where they are mounted.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of snaps!

Comment: thanks @ArturMeinild may I delete those snap partitions? Why did not I see these many previously??

Comment: No not really. If you remove the snaps, the partions will go as well. But this is how snap works - you can't change that.

Comment: thanks @ArturMeinild and all people who answered this question. :)

Comment: Loop mounts are not partitions. Loop mounts are [loop mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/what-is-a-loop-device-when-mounting). Partitions are partitions.